# メソッドをhelperからdecoratorに移動すると undefined method `term' のエラーが発生する

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

もともとuser_helper.rbに記述していたメソッドを新しく作成したcareer_decorator.rbに移動したいのですが、undefined method `term' for #のエラーがでます。
いくら考えて、実行しても改善できないので質問させていただきました。
以下は現状のコードです

career_decorator.rb (user_helper.rbから移動したコード)

```
module CareerDecorator

  def term
    start_date = l(start_date, format: :term)

    if end_date.blank?
      "#{start_date} - #{t('date.formats.ongoing')}"
    else
      "#{start_date} - #{l(end_date, format: :term)}"
    end
  end

  def distance_of_term
    if end_date.blank?
      t('datetime.distance_in_words.ongoing')
    else
      distance_of_time_in_words(start_date, end_date)
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/users/user.html.slim

```
@user.careers.order('start_date desc, end_date desc').each do |career|
  tr
    td
      p = link_to career.term, edit_user_career_path(user_id: @user, id: career)
      p = career.distance_of_term
      td = career.title
```

user_helper.rb（もともとはこのファイルの以下のようなtermとdestance_of_termメソッドがあり、これをcareer_decorator.rbに移動したい）

```
module UsersHelper
  def term(career)
    start_date = l(career.start_date, format: :term)

      if career.end_date.blank?
        "#{start_date} - #{t('date.formats.ongoing')}"
      else
        "#{start_date} - #{l(career.end_date, format: :term)}"
      end
    end

  def distance_of_term(career)
    if career.end_date.blank?
      t('datetime.distance_in_words.ongoing')
    else
      distance_of_time_in_words(career.start_date, career.end_date)
    end
  end
end
```

careerがtermメソッドを持っていないことはなんとなくわかっていますがどうしたら良いのかわかりません。

自分なりの考え

- helperからdecoratorに該当メソッドを移動する時にコピペだけだとだめっぽい=>decoratorのメソッドを変更するのか
- モデルのアソシエーション操作が必要なのか?
- decorator.rbは手打ちではなくコマンドで作成しないといけないのか？？=> rails g decorator careerとやったらgem周りでエラーが出ました
- careerオブジェクトがtermメソッドを持っていない
- users_controller.rbのshowにcareerのインスタンスを作成する必要がありそう

ヒントいただければ幸いです。

Comment: 何か gem をお使いかと思うのですが、[drapergem/draper: Decorators/View-Models for Rails Applications](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) ですか？

Comment: 返信遅れてしまい大変申し訳ありませんでした。
ActiveDecoratorを使っています。
検索を重ねた結果
@user.careers.order('start_date desc, end_date desc').each do |career| 
p = link_to **ActiveDecorator::Decorator.instance.decorate(career).term** 

上記のようにshow.html.slimを変更し、エラー回避できました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

回答をしてくださった方々ありがとうございます。検索しながら行い、なんとか自力でエラー回避できましたので、参考になればと思い自分で回答させていただきます。 
今回の問題はDecoratorを呼び出せていなかったことだったのですが、以下のように記述することでエラー回避できるようになりました!

```
@user.careers.order('start_date desc, end_date desc').each do|career| 
p = link_to ActiveDecorator::Decorator.instance.decorate(career).term
```

> ActiveDecorator::Decorator.instance.decorate(career).termとすることで、decoratorを適用させるよ‌​という役割になるそうです。

Answer (score 0):

ActiveDecoratorをお使いですか?
https://github.com/amatsuda/active_decorator

ActiveDecoratorでは、以下の場合、自動でモデルにmoduleをmixinしてくれます。(READMEから引用しました)

> 1. automatically mixes decorator module into corresponding model only when:
>      i. passing a model or collection of models or an instance of  ActiveRecord::Relation from controllers to views
>      ii. rendering partials with models (using :collection or :object or :locals explicitly or implicitly)

雑に訳すると以下のようなタイミングです。

i. モデル、もしくはActiveRecord::Relationのインスタンスをコントローラからviewに渡すとき
ii. モデルをpartialに渡したとき

なので、コントローラの中で以下のようにインスタンス変数に入れてviewに渡すようにすると、1の動作になり、termメソッドが使えるようになると思います。

```
@careers = @user.careers
```

app/views/users/user.html.slim

```
@careers.order('start_date desc, end_date desc').each do |career|
  tr
    td
      p = link_to career.term, edit_user_career_path(user_id: @user, id: career)
      p = career.distance_of_term
      td = career.title
```

Comment: とてもわかりやすい回答頂き大変ありがとうございます。
また、返信が遅れてしまったこと申し訳ありません。
問題はDecoratorを呼び出せていなかったことで、以下のように記述することでエラー回避できるようになりました!
@user.careers.order('start_date desc, end_date desc').each do |career|
p = link_to **ActiveDecorator::Decorator.instance.decorate(career).term**

ActiveDecorator::Decorator.instance.decorate(career).termとすることで、decoratorを適用させるよという役割になるそうです。

だいぶ時間かけて悩んでしまいましたが、非常にためになりました。

Comment: @roy2456 なるほど。`ActiveDecorator::Decorator.instance.decorate`を呼んで明示的にDecoratorを適用する方法でも解決できますね。

他の人の参考になると思うので、コメント欄だけに回答を書かずに、自分の質問に対して、自分で回答して、回答を承認して解決済みにしましょう!
参考: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer